# PHP Parse HTML file

Tags: php, html, parsing

I need to parse a HTML file without any ID's or classes.

There are many tables with only a few rows.

Now I want to access the elements like in jq

```
jQuery("<tr>").children("<td>")...
```

I started with PHP DOMDocument and I can get elements with

```
$doc->getElementsByTagName(...)
```

But I cant find a method to access the child elements.

Does somebody have an idea?

Comment: You can use `$doc->getElementsByTagName(...)->childNodes` to get a list of all children and then iterate through that for filtering or whatever.

Comment: Post your HTML Code sample

Comment: Ah okay, now i understand :-)
Thank You

Comment: @GauravRai
This are simple structed html tables with n rows and x cells. arkascha answer solved the problem. Thanks for help guys